# Issue with Razor MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

MVC 3 RC

I registered both System.Web.Razor and System.Web.WebPages.Razor and still have System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup not recognized in my View/web.Config

Intellisence for Razor is not working
What can be wrong with my configuration

Comment: Yes I did
It is the first thing I mentionned in my post

Comment: Registering the dlls and installing MVC 3 isn't the same thing.

Comment: This might sound stupid, what project type are you using, and what target? Client Profile will not work.

Comment: BuildStart, I started my post by saying MVC3 RC

Comment: Mattew,
No, it is not targeting Client Profile but classical .Net Framework 4
It is a classical MVC application that works perfectly well with ASPx Web Engine.

Answer (score 5):

Add the assembly "System.Web.WebPages.Razor" to the ***main* Web.config** of the application.
For some reason the "ASP.NET MVC 3 Web Application" project template included in the RC1 does not fill it.

```
<add assembly="System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
```

Comment: +1: I had the same problem as the OP, your solution was the only one that solve it. BTW, I *guess* this is in fact a **ReSharper** issue (I'm using it, not sure if the OP is too).

Answer (score 0):

It's not obvious from your question or the comments if you've done it, but in order to have full support for Razor in your system you need to *install* the runtime and the tooling using the following installer: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=a920ccee-1397-4feb-824a-2dfefee47d54

Just putting the MVC 3 runtime binaries in your application and making changes to web.config is not enough to make Razor IntelliSense work in Visual Studio.

Comment: Marcind, I did install MVC3 RC I did not change anything to my web config However, if I create a new MVC3 RC project and select RAZOR as my default View engine, I do not have intellisence When I open the web.config file in my view directory, I can see there a reference to System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup but it is not recognized (it is in red) So I added as reference both System.Web.Razor and System.Web.WebPages.Razor

Answer (score 0):

The problem disappeared from the time I removed Resharper